# Summarise names using a column value as a pre-filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following df as example:

```
df <- data.frame(status = c(rep("egr", 5), rep("ing", 5)),
                 ua = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 fam = c(rep("fam1", 2), rep("fam2", 7), "fam3"),
                 spp = c(rep("spp1", 3), rep("spp2", 3), "rep4", "rep5", rep("spp6", 2)))
```

What I'm trying to do is `summarise` the count of strings based on a `group_by` of the `ua` column and the differences between the names of `fam` and `spp` when comparing the two `status` (ing, egr).

In other words, for each `ua`, I want to count via `summarise` the differences between `ing` - `egr` for each other column (`spp` and `fam`). I'm having an issue specifically assigning the `status` column as the base for the differences, i.e., getting the names of `spp` and `fam` at each `status` before summarizing. A `setdiff` between `fam` or `spp` from each `status` seems enough, but I'm failing at, again, assigning the `status` before the summary.

EDIT:

Getting the different number of names in `ing` minus `egr`, an output might look like

```
output <- data.frame(ua = c(1, 2),
                     fam = c(-1, 2),
                     spp = c(1, 1))
```

Example rationale:

`ua` 1 has, considering both `egr` and `ing`, two names of `fam` (fam1 and fam2). Since fam2 is shared between `ing` and `egr`, the diff is 0. But `egr` has also `fam1`, then the difference became -1.

Another example: `ua` 2 has no `egr`, then the sum is simply 2 (fam2 and fam3).

Again: `ua` 1 has, considering both `ing` and `egr`, four `spp` (spp1, spp2, rep4, rep5). Doing the `ing` minus `egr`, it must result in 1 because `ing` has two unique names and (rep4 and rep5) and `egr` one (spp1). Thus, the diff of `ing` - `egr` is 1 since spp2 is shared

I hope this is understandable, it's kinda tricky to explain.

Comment: Could you show the expected output somehow?

Comment: I edited. Thanks for asking. I hope it's understandable. If anything, I can try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could work, although rather convoluted:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(fam:spp) %>%
  distinct %>%
  group_by(ua, name, value) %>%
  filter(n() == 1L) %>%
  group_by(ua, name) %>%
  summarise(value = n_distinct(value[status == 'ing']) - n_distinct(value[status == 'egr'])) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ua, names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ua [2]
     ua   fam   spp
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1    -1     1
2     2     2     1
```

Comment: I tried some examples with my data, and your answer worked correctly compared to the other, so I accepted your answer. Question: if I want to keep the raw values that were used to get to the final answer (the diff between ing and egr), what should I add in summarise()?

i tried to group_by(ua, name, status) but that returns to me a df composed of a vector and two lists (one for fam and other for spp).

Comment: It depends on what format you'd like to have them. Perhaps if you amend your question and add data example we could help

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @arg0naut91's answer, but instead of pivoting the data, we `complete` the data:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(ua, status) %>% #for each ua and status
  summarise(across(c(fam, spp), ~ length(unique(.x))), .groups = "drop") %>% #get the number of unique values (~ n_distinct(.x)) would also work
  complete(ua, status, fill = list(fam = 0, spp = 0)) %>% #complete the data such that every ua has both status (but with 0's if the row was missing)
  arrange(status) %>% #arrange the data so we get the `diff` in the correct order
  group_by(ua) %>%
  summarise(across(c(fam, spp), ~ diff(.x)))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     ua   fam   spp
  <dbl> <int> <int>
1     1    -1     1
2     2     2     1
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked wonders! I'll keep your answer as the accepted since it's easier for me to understand